# Decimal sorting with Telerik Radgridview Column

Tags: silverlight, telerik-grid, rad-controls

I am Using telerik radcontrols with silverlight4.0. Here I am having currency column in my radgridview, but the problem happening it is not getting sorted in ascending and descending way, For example:

```
 1500.44 , 12229.21 , 1021.30 230.15 , 1400.36
```

The order should be

```
230.15,1021.30,1400.36,1500.44,12229.21
```

Could anyone please throw a light how we can acquire the sorting these values?

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Price" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" DataFormatString="#,#.000" TextAlignment="Right" Width="80"/>
```

for sorting:

```
 <telerik:RadGridView.SortDescriptors>
                    <telerik:SortDescriptor Member="Price" SortDirection="Descending"/>
 </telerik:RadGridView.SortDescriptors>
```